# How can I obtain an IPv4LL address when dhcp server is down?

Tags: networking, dhcp, avahi

I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` with the lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

but, if the dhcp server is down, I want the interface obtains automatically a link-local address.
Is it possible? Or do I have to re-configure the `/etc/network/interfaces` with the lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet ipv4ll
```

everytime the dhcp server is down?

Answer (score 0):

have you installed avahi-autoipd package? It has hooks for dhcp client which do just what you asked for. Use the first configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```